# Create Eventlisteners for detailstag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, html-tag-details

Why is this working:

```js
const details = document.querySelector('details')

document.getElementById("details1").addEventListener("toggle", event => {
  if (details1.open) {
    changeText1("open");
  } else {
    changeText1("closed");
  }
});

document.getElementById("details2").addEventListener("toggle", event => {
  if (details2.open) {
    changeText2("open");
  } else {
    changeText2("closed");
  };
});


function changeText1(status) {
 if(status == "open") {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerText = "opened";
    } else if (status == "closed") {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerText = "closed";
    }
} 

function changeText2(status) {
 if(status == "open") {
    document.getElementById("p2").innerText = "opened";
    } else if (status == "closed") {
    document.getElementById("p2").innerText = "closed";
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<details id="details1">
  <summary>#1</summary>text
</details>
<details id="details2">
  <summary>#2</summary>text
</details>

<p id="p1">not opened or closed</p>
<p id="p2">not opened or closed</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And is this not working:

```js
const details = document.querySelector('details')

function changeText(detailnr, status) {
 let pnr = "p" + detailnr; 
 if(status == "open") {
    document.getElementById(pnr).innerText = "opened";
    } else {
    document.getElementById(pnr).innerText = "closed";
    }
}

function maaklistner(detailsnr){
 let detailsid = "details" + detailsnr; 
 document.getElementById(detailsid).addEventListener("toggle", event => {
  if (detailsid.open) {
    changeText(detailsnr, "open");
  } else {
    changeText(detailsnr, "closed");
  } 
});
}


for(let i = 1; i < 3; i++){
 maaklistner(i); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<details id="details1">
  <summary>#1</summary>text
</details>
<details id="details2">
  <summary>#2</summary>text
</details>

<p id="p1">not opened or closed</p>
<p id="p2">not opened or closed</p>

</body>
</html>
```

While the code in essence is exactly a duplicate...

Seems like the eventlistener itself IS created. But, the details.opened statement IS NOT treated correctly at the seconde code, while the same methode does work at the first code.

Is there a way to get the second method working? Since I need to create more then 2000 of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `document.getElementById(detailsid)` in place of `detailsid`

```js
const details = document.querySelector('details')

function changeText(detailnr, status) {
  let pnr = "p" + detailnr;
  if (status == "open") {
    document.getElementById(pnr).innerText = "opened";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(pnr).innerText = "closed";
  }
}

function maaklistner(detailsnr) {
  let detailsid = "details" + detailsnr;
  
  document.getElementById(detailsid).addEventListener("toggle", event => {
    if (document.getElementById(detailsid).open) {
      changeText(detailsnr, "open");
    } else {
      changeText(detailsnr, "closed");
    }
  });
}


for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  maaklistner(i);
}
```

```html
<details id="details1">
  <summary>#1</summary>text
</details>
<details id="details2">
  <summary>#2</summary>text
</details>

<p id="p1">not opened or closed</p>
<p id="p2">not opened or closed</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you use `detailsid` to check if the `details` element is open. You need to use the elements that contain the id `detailsid`.

Just replace `detailsid.open` with `document.getElementById(detailsid).open`.

Here is an example that is working:

```js
const details = document.querySelector('details')

function changeText(detailnr, status) {
  let pnr = "p" + detailnr;
  if (status == "open") {
    document.getElementById(pnr).innerText = "opened";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(pnr).innerText = "closed";
  }
}

function maaklistner(detailsnr) {
  let detailsid = "details" + detailsnr;
  
  document.getElementById(detailsid).addEventListener("toggle", event => {
    if (document.getElementById(detailsid).open) {
      changeText(detailsnr, "open");
    } else {
      changeText(detailsnr, "closed");
    }
  });
}


for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  maaklistner(i);
}
```

```html
<details id="details1">
  <summary>#1</summary>text
</details>
<details id="details2">
  <summary>#2</summary>text
</details>

<p id="p1">not opened or closed</p>
<p id="p2">not opened or closed</p>
```

Comment: ahh, faster than me, congrats bro

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to forget about unique ids here... You can set an event listener for each `details` element using a `forEach` loop.

A `data-*` attribute will hold the index (zero-based) of the `p` to target for text change.

Have a look! It is much simpler.

```js
// Get all the details elements
let details = document.querySelectorAll("details");

// Get an array from all the p elements
let stateIndicators = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".stateWrapper p"))

// For each details element, set an event listener
details.forEach(function(detail) {
  detail.addEventListener("toggle", function(e) {
  
    // Get its index from the data attribute
    let index = this.dataset.index
    
    // Change the text based on the open state
    stateIndicators[index].innerText = this.open ? "opened" : "closed"
  })
})
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <details data-index="0">
    <summary>#1</summary>text
  </details>
  <details data-index="1">
    <summary>#2</summary>text
  </details>
  <details data-index="2">
    <summary>#3</summary>text
  </details>
  <details data-index="3">
    <summary>#4</summary>text
  </details>
  <details data-index="4">
    <summary>#5</summary>text
  </details>

  <div class="stateWrapper"><!-- usefull wrapper here -->
    <p>not opened or closed</p>
    <p>not opened or closed</p>
    <p>not opened or closed</p>
    <p>not opened or closed</p>
    <p>not opened or closed</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't doubt this is a smarter way, only thing is, I'm just a few days into javascript, and the real code I need to apply it to is more complicated. Every details hold a table and value (Picture) which is determined by combining other cells (only if details is opened, to prevent lots of loading). So, how would you write it when, for example, the 'text'-text :-) after each summary differs, and instead of showing 'opened' you want the 'nr + text' shown? I can't get that done your way (must be me), the 'less elegant way'  its working now.

Answer (score 1):

Use "click" event since "toggle" doesn't bubble. Event bubbling is needed to use [Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) which allows you to add a single event handler to listen for events for an unlimited amounr of tags including dynamically added tags.

```js
const flipDetails = event => {
  const parent = event.currentTarget;
  const clicked = event.target;
  const nodes = [...parent.children];
  const log = document.querySelector('output');
  if (clicked !== parent && clicked.matches('summary')) {
    let dtl = clicked.parentElement;
    let pos = nodes.indexOf(dtl)+1;
    let status = dtl.open === true ? `${pos}: Closed` : `${pos}: Open`;
    log.innerHTML += '<br>'+ status;
  }
}

const main = document.querySelector('main');

main.addEventListener("click", flipDetails);

// For demo only
document.querySelector('output').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `
    <details>
      <summary>Added Dynamically</summary>text
    </details>`);
```

```css
output::before {content: 'Status: '}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main>
    <details>
      <summary>#1</summary>text
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary>#2</summary>text
    </details>
    <output></output>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```